# datapager with datalist control

Tags: asp.net

i need  to implement   paging concept in datalist control.  i had  implement  paging in datalist  like **prev and  last**
 but   now i  wanted  the  paging to be  like

```
     **prev  1 2 3 4 5  next**
```

**have  any one  implemented like  this  for paging in datalist  control**
 or **datapager  control   to get this  function  done**

or any  url  which  can  help me  to  solve this issue  would  be  great

thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET 3.5, you can use ListView and DataPager controls instead.

Comment: does  listview  supports repeat direction property?
repeat columns?
 i doubt  wheather it supports these property

Comment: ListView does not support these properties but it's so flexible and you can create your own layout. Check it out. http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/127340.aspx